# using nativescript-audio is throwing can not find module error

Tags: mp3, nativescript

I want to play mp3 in native script application. and I followed this introduction, https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-audio to install nativescript-audo.

But when I run, I met this error:

```
file:///app/modules/rss_player/detail.component.js:7:35: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module 'nativescript-audio'
```

I used this first:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-audio
```

then

```
import { TNSPlayer } from 'nativescript-audio';

this._player = new TNSPlayer();
```

Can anyone tell me where is the error?

Do I have to import any special module? but which one?

The git for this plugin is:

https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio/tree/master/demo/app

Thanks

Comment: Using github's issue tracker might be a better place for the kind of errors that you are facing. Check out the latest issue, perhaps it concerns exactly what you are experiencing. https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio/issues/68

Comment: Thank you! Got it